# how Stop or cancel all instant of AsyncTask in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have create one AsyncTask for download images from server.
AsyncTask will call number of time. on i want to cancel that AsyncTask on single button click.

Comment: Keep references of the tasks, and call `cancel()` on them

Comment: go through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use Cancel Method for this

```
 asyncTask.cancel( true );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cancelling a task

A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

see AsyncTask [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for details

basically hold a reference to your `AsyncTaks` and call `AsyncTask#cancel(true)` from the `onClickListener` of your `Button`